# clever way to avoid repetition in Perlin noise

Tags: gradient, noise, perlin-noise

Hey is there an (easy) way to avoid that Perlin Noise will repeat after a while? I want to use it for endless terrain and do not want to have the same terrain over and over again so i need a solution for this. I would also combine it with fractal brownian motion and write it on the gpu with hls to save some calculation-time.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, yes.

The repetition you wish to avoid is due to using only the low 16 bits (frequently lowest 8 bits) to determine which pseudo-random gradient vector to associate with each vertex.  To get the arbitrarily large repetition scale you desire I would recommend using a wrapped hash for the vertices.

I.e: let Xn = x & 255, Yn = y & 255, etc, then instead of using perm[Xn + perm[Yn]], replace them with a new Xi = (x&255) ^ ((x / 256) & 255) ^ ((x >> 16) & 255) ^ ((x >> 24) & 255) ^ ...
{The bitwise (X)OR being used instead of addition to ensure no overflow occurs in the look up table that is randomizing vector assignment.}

Then use the perm[Xi] ^ perm[Yi]  (or perm[Xi + perm[Yi]], whatever) for the gradient selection process.

This way the higher-multiple (large scale) index of your points continues to effect the assignment of noise vectors.

Since you are using fBm as well, your terrain will only truly repeat after all the octaves sync, so if you use a dissonant chord it will take longer.  {that being not the simple 2**n normally used, this option however definitely increases the computation time as you would be actually using integer division rather than bit-shifts.}  Using the sequence of primes should give the most extreme repetition length possible.  Depending on your choice of persistence parameter however, such a treatment may not be worth the extra flops, or even noticeable.